# Excel 2016 - How to fill one cell with data from multiply checkboxes?

Tags: excel, if-statement, checkbox, vba

For starters, im not very great or smart when it comes to Excel. So forgive me my question, since it might be really easy, but i just cant get it to work.

I have look though google and cant seem to find a solution for this, or anything that can help me in the right direction.

I have a list of checkboxes in excel, from `D4` to `D27`.
I have every value of the checkboxes on `E4` to `E27` (`TRUE` or `FALSE`).

Then i have a cell that should get the data from the checkboxes, when they are TRUE. This is `B27`.

`B27` have a `=IF(E4=TRUE; "YaY"; "Nope")` script at the moment. And this is working. BUT, i cant get anymore `IF statements` in there, or nest them when it comes to text. I might be doing it wrong though, i dont know. -Yes i did try and look it but, but cant get it to work.

Every checkbox has diffrent data linked to it, so if `D4` is checked, then the value need to be sent to `B27`, with text `YAY!`. And then if `D5` is checked, it sends the data to `B27` with some other data, lets say `WOO!`. So `B27` should be looking like this : `YAY!; WOO!;`

|------------------------------------------------------|
|-------D4---------|----------E4--------------------|
|-------X-----------|---------TRUE----------------|
|-------X-----------|---------TRUE----------------|
|-------B27--------|---------YAY!; WOO!;-------|
|------------------------------------------------------|

How can i get this done?

I have tried to look at Macro scripting as well, but that was a great failure.

Can someone show me in the right direction, or help me out how this can be done?

Comment: `Concatenate(IF(E4=TRUE; "YaY"; "Nope"),IF(E5=TRUE; "Woo!"; "Boo!"))` (of course, this can get very long, perhaps too long if you are trying to do it for 23 different cells)

Comment: Where are the words that you need to concatenate in B7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description I would solve it as follows:

- Col. D: Checkboxes
- Col. E: TRUE/FALSE statements (based on used checkbox)
- Col. F: Answer if statement is TRUE (e.g. YAY!)
- Col. G: Answer if statement is FALSE (e.g. Nope!)

Then you can use the following formula in B27:

```
=IF(E4,F4,G4)&" " & IF(E5,F5,G5) &" " & IF(E..,F..,G..)
```

Based on the logical result in E, you get the desired answer in cell B27. Using the "&" you can combine all if statements.

Comment: I dont see how this can be used for my setup? I need the answer in B27, but if i go by your solution, i need two Col's for both true and false answers? or maybe im understanding your solution wrong?